# Why does jvm not use all available memory?

Tags: java

I set the jvm -Xmx1536m argument and it fails to start due to not enough free memory even though available memory is ~2.5GB.

More closely inspecting my Windows 7 Task Manager, I realized it says free memory: 1.1GB, available memory: 1.6GB, and after testing I realized that the vm starts with no problem with -Xmx up to the amount of free memory, but it cant go higher even though there's more available memory, do you know why this is?